# How to download large amounts of data over TCP in python?

Tags: python, tcp, client-server

So far in my project, I have been using the following solution to download data. The amount of data was small, so there was no problem:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('192.168.0.10', 6100)
sock.connect(server_address)
sock.send(*** here is command to server***)
data = sock.recv(1024)
sock.close()
```

Now, I need to download a larger amount of data from the server, and it turns out that my solution only retrieves a portion of it. I have read that the problem may be the maximum size of a TCP packet. I tried to solve it using the following code:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('192.168.0.10', 6100)
sock.connect(server_address)
sock.send((*** here is command to server***)

data = b''
while True:
    try:
        chunk = sock.recv(1024)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    if not chunk:
        chunk = str(repr(data.decode()))
        sock.close()
        break
    data += chunk
print(f"Received data: {data}")
```

This loop works by adding successive parts of the data stream to "data". Unfortunately, when the data is finished, the script hangs. What am I doing wrong?

I should mention that I have no control over the server. I can only obtain a ready-made data packet from it through a request. I cannot control it to send me parts of the packet. Everything must happen on my side, that is, on the client side.
The data packet always ends with "\x00" Can I use this somehow?

Comment: You need to send some kind of sentinel to indicate the end of data. Either that, or send a preamble that tells the receiver how many bytes are going to be delivered

Comment: The data packet always ends with "\x00"
Can I use this somehow?

Comment: @Marcin: recv and check for \x00. If it is not found read more. If it is found stop reading.

Comment: where do you exit the loop?

Comment: I updated my solution with the braek command but it still doesn't work

Comment: @SteffenUllrich how a can do it?  I tri but still not work :D

Comment: @Marcin: *"I tri but still not work"* - nothing in the code you show suggests that you've tried to check for \x00 and break the loop when found. Please update your question with what you've tried.

Comment: Are multiple data packets sent on a single connection, each terminated by a null?  Or is it one packet per connection, and then the connection is closed?  If the latter, then append all the chunks together until you get an empty chunk signifying that the connection is closed, and no need to check for the null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to you, I found a solution that works :)

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('192.168.0.10', 6100)
sock.connect(server_address)
sock.send(*** here is command to server***)

data = b""

while True:
    chunk = sock.recv(1024)
    data += chunk
    if '\x00' in str(chunk.decode()):
        break
print(data)
```

Comment: This may work but is very inefficient for large data transmissions because of the way you're searching for a NUL byte. You could just inspect *chunk[-1]*

Comment: @CtrlZ Probably you are right. But in my case it's quite an effective solution. It is used to search all scenes in the database of the graphics engine working in a television studio. Data are the paths to these elements. There are a lot of them, but not very many ;-)

Comment: If a single packet is sent from one connection, then `sock.recv(1024)` will return `''` when the socket is closed.  No need to check for a null byte at the end.  If these are binary "scenes" you may also get null bytes in the data before then end of the "scene".